# Do I need a table in my DB for each users info?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have found similar questions but none that directly answer my question. Having never built a DB from scratch before I'm not sure how to handle this.

I am building a coupon savings tracker for my girlfriend and her friends that tracks their expenses and savings in each shopping trip. What I want to know is where I can learn how to build the DB in such a way that I can query for the data by user name or similar key.

I believe I'm just overcomplicating this. I'm thinking one table for user login info (email, login ID, and hashed password) and then build another table for their inputted data. There will only be like 7 or 8 columns but possibly several thousand records or more. Then I can simply do a join on the two tables at the user ID when I query for the records. Am I on the right track? ...and if not, where can I go to get a better understanding?

Comment: Start with ER mapping and database normalization. Lots of tutorials out there. Google it.

Comment: Perfect. This actually helped quite a bit. I just needed the right terms to google. Thanks Jay!

Comment: Go through this link (Normalization): http://searchbusinessintelligence.techtarget.in/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have the right idea for the schema. The user table should have a primary key `id`, and the other table will have a foreign key `user_id`. Join on those columns, and you should be good!

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking but I wasn't sure. Thanks Brian!